# Best way to adjust work global dim and local (block) dim

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

I am trying to run a kernel on the gpu. I am looking for the best way to adjust the global and local dimensions of the grid of threads. In my experiments, I understood 32 block threads made of 1 threads is 32 times faster than 1 block of 32 threads (on my nvidia GTX 980). Before, I was using the following way to determine the kernel grid dimensions:

```
  size_t local_ws = 32; 
  size_t nKernels = num_seeding_points;
  local_ws = local_ws > nKernels ? nKernels : local_ws;
  size_t global_ws = (nKernels + local_ws - 1) / local_ws * local_ws;
```

but I understood if the number of kernels are not big, this way will not use my GPU completely, and we I changed this part to:

```
  size_t local_ws = 1; 
  size_t nKernels = num_seeding_points;
  local_ws = local_ws > nKernels ? nKernels : local_ws;
  size_t global_ws = (nKernels + local_ws - 1) / local_ws * local_ws;
```

My code runs 20 times faster than before. I wanted to see how can I compute the best possible values for running my kernel. Definitely, your experiences will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to auto-tune global and local work sizes you should first query your kernel object and/or your device for the following info:

Useful kernel info (using the `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo()` function):

- CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: Maximum block size that can be used to execute a kernel on a specific device.
- CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE: Get the preferred multiple for the block size. This is a performance hint, and is probably the most important piece of information to optimize you global and local work sizes.

If you didn't yet create a kernel object when you determine the global and local work sizes, you can instead query your device for similar info (using the `clGetDeviceInfo()` function):

- CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES: Maximum number of threads that can be specified in each dimension of the block.
- CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: Maximum number of threads in a block.

Starting from the actual size of the work you want to process (i.e. `num_seeding_points`), and using the information provided by the aforementioned functions, you can optimize the global and local work sizes for whatever OpenCL device you're using. Most importantly, always try to make your local work size a multiple of CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE.

Note that for small global sizes (lower than 128 or 256) you won't see much benefit with these optimizations.

I wrote a function for the [cf4ocl](https://github.com/FakenMC/cf4ocl/) library called `ccl_kernel_suggest_worksizes()` that suggests optimum global and local work sizes given the size of the work you want to process, a device, and optionally, a kernel object. Check its source code [here](https://github.com/FakenMC/cf4ocl/blob/master/src/cf4ocl2/ccl_kernel_wrapper.c), maybe it gives some additional hints.

Comment: I looked at your function, I did not understand what will it do if the work_size is 32, will it generate 32 blocks of 1 task or 1 block of 32 tasks?

Comment: If CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE is 32 (common for NVidia), most likely it will suggest 1 block of 32 tasks, which should be optimal for a work size of 32.

Comment: but that's not optimal. The best choice is 32 blocks of 1 task which it can use all the SMMs together like cores of cpu.

Comment: I find it strange that your code is 20x faster using 32 blocks of 1 task. This is usual for the AMD OpenCL CPU implementation, but not for any OpenCL GPU implementation. Are you sure you're using the NVidia GPU device? Have you consistently observed this speedup? How are you measuring computation times? What kernel are you running? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I am using a GTX 980 + GTX 970. Yes. I see this speed up consistently. The start time is measured by getting the time before calling `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` and end time is measure by getting the time after `clFinish`. I think this is the correct way.

Comment: You can't think of SMMs as CPU cores, because each SMM has a bunch of shader units (CUDA cores) which are able to process a lot of concurrent computation. Does your kernel have lots of divergent code, e.g. if's and for's? It's the only way I see that you can get such results. (Yes, your timing it right, but what functions are you using to perform the timing?)

Comment: Yes. The problem is exactly in this point. My kernel has lots of if's and for's and it also has lots of global memory accesses.

Comment: Also, for timing I am using the `chrono` from `boost`.

Comment: Well, in that case your kernel is not really optimized for running on the GPU.  Within each SMM, all kernel instances (threads) should be processing the same line of code in SIMD fashion (Single Instruction, Multiple Data). Because your kernel is very divergent, your code is being serialized within the SMM. This does not happen when you run one thread per SMM: because SMMs are independent, your kernel will run in parallel in this case. However, you have a limited number of SMMs (16), so as soon as you increase the size of your work, you will have very slow computation.

Comment: You have two choices: either run your kernel on the CPU (use Intel's or AMD OpenCL implementations for the CPU), it will be faster. OR reformulate your kernel in SIMD fashion, so it can run efficiently on the GPU. You have to understand that the performance hint returned by CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE expects that you run SIMD-like kernels, not typical C function-like kernels.

Comment: That's right! But still this is a good point as I can use both CPU and GPU together with the same kernel and GPU is 10 times faster than CPU. Also, I have reformulated the kernel as much as I could to run on the GPU but `Stream line tracing` kernel in unstructured grid is not that SIMD friendly.

Comment: Well, if your kernel can't be made more SIMD-friendly, then you have yourself a corner case in which the performance hints are not of much use. I do find it strange that running the kernel on the CPU is slower though (you're using all CPU cores right?). Maybe it's related to JIT compile times, as NVidia actively caches compiled kernels. Anyway, for this type of computations I think it would be simpler and more efficient to use an optimized CPU approach, either with OpenCL, OpenMP or with Boost threads. Good luck.

Comment: I am using all the cpu cores and my cpu is Core i7-4960X which is a pretty fast CPU with 6 cores with 3.6 Ghz clock but still 980 is working far better than CPU.